# Hibernate with EHCache - Save on any non-cached entity it putting it in Cache

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I am trying to use 2nd level caching for Hibernate with EHCache. I have some entities configured in the application that I have tagged with @Cache and I see that they are used by EHCache correctly.

However what I have observed is that when I save/update any other entity that is not supposed to be cached; I see that it gets added to the cache by the put() method. The retrieval of the data does NOT put the non-cached object into the cache.

This behaviour doesn't seem right to me as we should only add the cached objects to the cache and not any object on the save/update operation.

Am I missing something here?

I see the entities being added in the logs when I do any save/update operation.

2011-07-15 22:02:28 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8080-1] EhcacheGeneralDataRegion.put(83) | key: mmd_addresses value: 5368822204260352 
2011-07-15 22:02:28 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8080-1] EhcacheGeneralDataRegion.put(83) | key: fqng_users value: 5368822205923328 
2011-07-15 22:02:29 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8080-1] EhcacheGeneralDataRegion.put(83) | key: fqng_link_user_applications value: 5368822209306624 
2011-07-15 22:02:30 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8080-1] EhcacheGeneralDataRegion.put(83) | key: mmd_addresses value: 5368821964824576 
2011-07-15 22:02:30 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8080-1] EhcacheGeneralDataRegion.put(83) | key: fqng_users value: 5368821964824576 
2011-07-15 22:02:30 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8080-1] EhcacheGeneralDataRegion.put(83) | key: fqng_link_user_applications value: 5368821964824576 
2011-07-15 22:05:55 DEBUG [http-0.0.0.0-8080-6] EhcacheGeneralDataRegion.put(83) | key: fqng_users value: 5368823053987840

None of these objects have the @Cache annotatation.

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "fqng_users", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "NAME")) 
// @Audited 
public class Users implements java.io.Serializable { 

@Entity 
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicUpdate = true) 
@Table(name = "mmd_addresses") 
// @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED) 
public class Addresses implements java.io.Serializable {
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm..the problem was with using the query cache with *org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache*. Needed some time with the Hibernate codebase to figure it out.

When using the *StandardQueryCache*; Hibernate keeps the latest updated timestamp for each table in the *UpdateTimestampsCache* so that it knows when was last the table was updated. This helps us to keep track if any entity in the query cache was updated after the query results were tracked.

Since Hibernate cannot keep track of exact entities, it add all the entities to the  *UpdateTimestampsCache* which were saved/updated. So essentially the put() that I was seeing was actually putting the entity types(specifically tables) in the  *UpdateTimestampsCache* and invalidating them and replacing with a new value whenever a entity of the same type was inserted/updated through Hibernate.